# Copy Cell From Range On Active Row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to copy a cell on the active row of a range.
A1:A10 is a range named "Panel_Length". I want to click a button to copy the cell from column "A" of the active row. The code works if I specify column "A" and active row but there is a chance that the range "Panel_Length" may get moved to another column.

```
Sub Plen_Click()

Dim PLength as Range
Set PLength = Sheet1.Range("Panel_Length")

Range(PLength & ActiveCell.Row).Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not just copy the active-cell, that's what you are doing anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand the question correct. but if you try to copy the cell from column of the named range and the row form the selected cell you can try the code below

```
Sub Plen_Click()

Sheet1.Cells(Selection.Row, Sheet1.Range("Panel_Length").Column).Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: if the named range is A1:A10. If A10 is selected, the cell that gets copied will be J1.

Comment: Thanks @Mark7000 for your response but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Sorry I flipt the collum and row parameter. I changed the original post.